# In tracker_sessions table in database user_id is showing null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, tracker

I am using laravel 5.2, in my database in `tracker_sessions` tables user_id it is not taking user id and geo_ip

Even I use the updated link https://github.com/Rainesdave/tracker.git which is include `\PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\TrackerMiddleware::class,`
into kernel middleware it still wont work.

Comment: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker/issues/129

Comment: @Kkinsey thanks for helping, but i have check the geoip already change to the latest version